# Gradle: How to exclude a particular package from a jar?

Tags: java, gradle

We have a package that is related to some requirements that were removed, but we don't want to necessarily delete the code because there's a possibility it will be needed again in the future.  So in our existing ant build, we've just excluded this package from being compiled in our jar.  These classes do not compile due to the fact that we've also removed their dependencies, so they can't be included in the build.

I'm attempting to mimic that functionality in Gradle as follows:

```
jar {
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src', '../otherprojectdir/src']

    include (['com/ourcompany/somepackage/activityadapter/**',
                 ...
        'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/**'])

    exclude(['com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/polling/**'])
}
```

Even with the exclude call above (and I've tried it without the square brackets as well), gradle is still attempting to compile the `polling` classes, which is causing compile failures.  How do I prevent Gradle from attempting to compile that package?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have some sources that you don't want to be compiled, you have to declare a filter for the sources, not for the class files that are put in the Jar. Something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            include 'com/ourcompany/somepackage/activityadapter/**'
            include 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/**'
            exclude 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/polling/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew I wasn't quite on target there :)

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your answer. The problem is the class was also found in other dependency of newer version. I want to use the newer version and exclude the class from older version.

Comment: @Achaius did you got the solution for this?

Comment: This solution is still valid and works like a charm as of April 27, 2023

Answer (score 44):

This solution is valid if you don´t want to compile these packages, but if you want to compile them and exclude from your JAR you could use

```
// tag::jar[]
jar {
    exclude('mi/package/excluded/**')   
    exclude('mi/package/excluded2/**')  
}
// end::jar[]
```

Comment: Unable to write jar in my build.gradle file, can you suggest me where can I code this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018:

> You may also use a closure or Spec to specify which files to include
>   or exclude. The closure or Spec is passed a FileTreeElement, and must
>   return a boolean value.

```
jar {
  exclude {
    FileSystems.getDefault()
      .getPathMatcher("glob:com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/polling/**")
      .matches(it.file.toPath())
  }
}
```

See [Jar.exclude](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:exclude(groovy.lang.Closure)), [FileTreeElement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTreeElement.html) and [Finding Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html).

Comment: not working with gradle 6: Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Could not get unknown property 'FileSystems' for task ':jar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.