# Exclude package from external JAR in Android Studio during Gradle build process

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar

Lets say I have an Android Studio project and JAR x.jar which I include in my build.gradle:

```
compile files('libs/x.jar')
```

How can I tell Gradle to not include the package xyz in the x.jar? Is there something like:

```
compile files('libs/x.jar'){
    exclude: "xyz"
}
```

Or is this not possible for a jar which I can't build myself (and exclude the sources while building the jar)?

Comment: I think you should be able to unjar it and rebuild ? (jar -xvf lib.jar )

Comment: Or : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19581593/1239966

Comment: @ShivamVerma doesn't this solution only work for code you created yourself? So before you compile the code as a jar you exclude parts of it but that does not work in the case of an already existing jar

Comment: `jar -xvf` lets you unjar, then you can select the parts of code that you want to create and then `jar cfm jar-file manifest-addition input-file(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle does not directly support a feature like this. Your only solution would be to create a task that generates a new jar and add this to your compile configuration.