# Remove a class and its implementation from production Android apk

Tags: android, build

I have some customised classes that perform functions like,

1. Custom Logging
2. Development Analytics
3. Extended features made available during app development
4. Custom mail management, and log file for Testers

When I have to send the app to production, we have to either

1. manually remove these codes, or
2. logically disable the features

This causes a couple of issues,

1. Security vulnerability
2. Manual effort of removal and sanity check

I was wondering if proGaurd or another build tool could be used to perform the same during the APK generation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the effect using gradle like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            include 'com/ourcompany/somepackage/activityadapter/**'
            include 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/**'
            exclude 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/polling/**'
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575474/gradle-how-to-exclude-a-particular-package-from-a-jar)

This requires consistent code architecture